# Deletar uma linha TableView + CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Estou criando uma aplicação com tabelas e persistência com `CoreData`, porém quando peço para apagar uma linha a mesma não some completamente da tela, deixando o simbolo...sumindo apenas quando vou para uma segunda tela e volto.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


    let managedObject : NSManagedObject = frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! NSManagedObject
    moc.deleteObject(managedObject)



    do{
        try moc.save()
    }catch{
        print("Error, data not saved!")
    }

        self.tableView.reloadData()


}
```

[image: Primeira tela antes de deletar] [image: Depois de deletar]

Comment: diminui o tamanho dessas imagens ai e posta o código que você esta utilizando para apagar, da uma lida nesse artigo aqui quando puder:http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Obrigado Gabriel, não estou com meu Mac agora, mais tarde posto a parte do código.

Comment: Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 2):

Aconselho que você passe a usar **NSFetchedResultController**. Isso é perfeito para lidar com edição de linhas + coredata em uma TableView.

Vou descrever um passo a passo básico do que você deve fazer pra conseguir começar a usar **NSFetchedResultController**:

1. Faça sua classe herdar de **NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate**;
2. Depois cria uma variável da seguinte forma:

   ```
   lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController = {
       let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "NomeDaSuaEntidade")
       fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "atributoParaOrdenar", ascending: true)]
       let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.sharedContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
       return fetchedResultsController
   }()
   ```
3. Na **viewDidLoad** adicione o seguinte trecho de código:

   ```
   ...
   do {
       try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
   } catch {}

   fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
   ...
   ```
4. Pra preencher a tabela no método **cellForRowAtIndePath** recupere os objetos da seguinte forma:

   ```
   ...
   let objeto = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! NomeDoSeuObjeto
   ...
   ```
5. No método **numberOfRowsInSection** recupere o número de itens da seguinte forma:

   ```
   ...
   let sectionInfo = self.fetchedResultsController.sections![section]
   return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects
   ...
   ```
6. Agora o grande charme do **NSFetchedResultController** que faz valer tanto a pena usar esse delegate o método que cuida das inserções, remoções, atualizações e movimentações de linhas da tabela:

   ```
   func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {
       switch type {
       case .Insert:
           self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
       case .Delete:
           self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
       case .Update:
           let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as! ArtistCell
           let artist = controller.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as! NomeDoSeuObjeto
           //preenche celula com dados do objeto
       case .Move:
           self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
           self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
       }
   }
   ```
7. Pra finalizar adicione os seguintes métodos pra que tudo funcione perfeitamente:

   ```
   func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
       self.tableView.beginUpdates()
   }

   func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
       self.tableView.endUpdates()
   }
   ```

Seguindo os passos acima você vai conseguir fazer a remoção de uma célula funcionar além de poder aproveitar de outros benefícios que esse delegate tem a oferecer.

Vou te passar também o link de um tutorial muito bom mostrando como se faz para poder complementar o que falei acima: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/core-data-and-swift-nsfetchedresultscontroller--cms-25072 (Sei que o tutorial está em Inglês, mas não achei nenhum bom em português)